# How to use SelectKBest for a classification problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, knn

I'm doing a classification Problem.

Assume this is my train and test dataset.

```
X_train.shape       y_train
(7500, 5760)        (7500,)

x_test.shape        y_test
(2500, 5760)        (2500,)
```

After using knn classifier I got an accuracy of 0.74%.

Now I want to select top 1000 features and again use knn and check my accuracy.

How do I use `SelectKBest` ?

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest, chi2

k_best = SelectKBest(chi2, k=1000)
```

Do I have to fit and transform both train and test dataset.

If I do these won't the features selected in train may differ from features selected in test?

I couldn't understand how to proceed? Please provide an example.

Comment: fit_transform X_train but only transform X_test and you are good to go.

Comment: @Alexis So If I do this will my train and test dataset have same top features??

Comment: yes because you will be using the top features of the train (you don't know the test top as you are testing your model)